# Using scope_builder to conditionally build a named scope in an Active Record model search() method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I'm using Ryan Bates' excellent [scope_builder](http://github.com/ryanb/scope-builder/tree/master) to conditionally build a new named scope to use in a search() method of an Active Record model.

The example documentation shows that you can do something like the following:

```
  # in product model
  def self.search(options)
    scope_builder do |builder|
      builder.released.visible
      builder.cheap if options[:cheap]
    end
  end
```

But, when I include the relevant version of the above code in my model and call search() with some options passed, what I get returned is an instance of ScopeBuilder::Builder and not the results of executing the chained named scope with the options I've passed, which is what I would expect.

My question is: **How do I get the results of executing builder(options) instead of an instance of the builder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the scope_builder block was [designed](http://github.com/ryanb/scope-builder/tree/master/README) to return the scope-builder instance, so you'll have to get the results from the instance.

Try using .all on the instance to grab the results.  For instance something like:

```
@results = Product.search().all
```

From [his tests](http://github.com/ryanb/scope-builder/tree/717b8f83dfb2ecdd5136eff018a319253e7bdc7b/spec/scope_builder/builder_spec.rb), it looks like this should work (line 47: "should be able to build up scope in block").

Comment: Yep, that totally works.  Thanks!  It should have occurred to me to look at the tests.  Great thinking.

Comment: I totally had to watch his railscast on named_scope again before it occurred to me.  Glad I could help!